# How can i create a anchor from categories?

Tags: magento2, frontend

How can i do an anchor with categories?

I want a menu that when I click on the subcategory send me a page created by me where all the subcategories are shown and the page takes you in the part of the page where the subcategory that I had clicked

I use Magento 2 v.2.2.4

Comment: Explain more to the question.

Comment: I want to go a specific part of the page using an anchor on my menu. For example, I have a shop,on Home page, on menu i have the categories of ever product, electronic, computers.. Then I have a page (categories) where are all the categories with all the products. Well, So when you click on menu from home page the direction from this category link will be to page categories and come in the middle of page that is where it is..